# What is minSDK for Percent Support Library?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-min-sdk, percent-support-library

I am not able to find it in official documentation, is there any info what is minSDK for new Percent Support Library?

Comment: this is support library , so you can you with this any api

Comment: @KWA checkout this demo for percent support library http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html

Comment: @nitesh How can this post answer the question?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti at the start of the post it have some pre-requestics which gives the information of things required during the time of development.Thereby helping them to atleast know if they need to updated something in there studio. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the aar file in your sdk folder.
In the `AndroidManifest.xml` you can find the minsdk.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SupportLibrary` was designed to take care of older Android versions.
You totally misunderstand purpose of library, better see documentation
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: I do understand. My question was "what is the lowest API I can use?". Even your link says "Each Support Library is backward-compatible to a specific Android API level.". So my question was - what is specific level for this library? Thanks to @Gabriele Mariotti I know that minSDK is 7.